# How to access the Environment Variable in Controller which is declared in Program.cs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an Environment variable that is assigned to a variable in Program.cs class. I want to access that in different controllers and pass it as a header to RestAPI calls. How can I achieve this?

In Program.cs I have read the environment variable and assigned it to a variable. I have created a class called EnvironmentVariableHelper which has the ReadValue method.

```
var key = EnvironmentVariableHelper.ReadValue(String.Empty, EnvironmentVariablesKeys.Key);
```

Now I want to pass this key value as a header to a RestAPI call in one of the methods in X Controller.

Comment: The environmental variable is string and you pass the string like any other string in a RestAPI.  So in this case you are creating a custom HTTP Header.  See : https://code-maze.com/aspnetcore-add-custom-headers/

Comment: Instead of assigning to a local variable, you can assign to a `static global` variable, that way it is available for all your controller classes.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran Sorry I am a newbie to C#. Can you please let me know how we can use that global variable in controller?

Comment: [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have an Environment variable that is assigned to a variable in
> Program.cs class. I want to access that in different controllers and
> pass it as a header to RestAPI calls. How can I achieve this?

It would great, if you would have shared your program.cs initialization and which environment variable you would like to read.

However, If you have initialized the class in program.cs file along with value, you can pass the class within the controller constructor in order to extract the value inside the controller action.

Let's assume, you have EnvironmentVariableHelperClass which you have initialized within your program.cs file as like below:

```
var configurationVariable = builder.Configuration
        .GetSection("MyCustomCredentials")
        .Get<EnvironmentVariableHelperClass>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton(configurationVariable);
```

Now, you can access the class value as key-value pairs within your controller as following:

```
public class ReadProgramcsValueController : Controller
    {

        private readonly EnvironmentVariableHelperClass _readFromProgramcsFile;
        public ReadProgramcsValueController(EnvironmentVariableHelperClass readProgramcsFile)
        {
            _readFromProgramcsFile = readProgramcsFile;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            //Now you can get the appsettings.json value
            var getConfiguration = _readFromProgramcsFile;
            return View();
        }
    }
```

Output:

I have  following credential, which I would like to initialize wihtin program.cs file and finally want to access in controller.

```
"MyCustomCredentials": {
    "From": "abc@gmail.com",
    "SmtpServer": "smtp.gmail.com",
    "Port": 587,
    "Username": "abc@gmail.com",
    "Password": "jirhklutcubguuul",
    "defaultCredentials" : "true"
  }
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET does this out of the box. In an ASP.NET template, the following is used and comes with many defaults regarding configuration.

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

- This loads configuration files, from appsettings.json and appsettings.{environment}.json
- This maps the environment variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to the configuration.
- and much more: read more here on the defaults: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

To consume the environment configuration from and MVC controller, you can just ask the IHostEnvironment interface by injecting it into your controller.

```cs
public class MoviesController : ControllerBase
{
     public MoviesController(IHostEnvironment environment)
     {
          string myEnvironment = environment.EnvironmentName;
     }
     //...
}
```

If you hit F5 (Run) in Visual Studio, you will likely see that `environment.EnvironmentName` is `"Development"`, because the template has the environment variable "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" set to "Development"
in the `launchSettings.json` file.

Alternate answer:

If you are writing an environment header in ALL your controllers, you can also use custom middleware instead of doing this for each controller.